# Mailing using Unix with error Files Attached

Tags: unix, grep, xargs, mailx

I have two Files (.csv) say `File1.csv` and `File2.csv` with `'INVALID'` records, generated at the end of a Informatica Job.

I am using below command to search for the file names `'INVALID'`, and then if either of the file has `'INVALID'` records I have to mail that particular file and if both has invalid records, both the files has to be mailed to the user.

```
$ grep -il "invalid" File1.csv File2.csv | xargs -I'{}' uuencode {} | mailx -s"files" mymail@gmail.com
```

I am getting mail with two files attached but with no records.

I also tried using -a to attach the file:

```
$ grep -il "invalid" File1.csv File2.csv | xargs -I'{}' mailx -s"files" -a {} mymail@gmail.com
```

But the above command is throwing error:

```
mailx: illegal option -- a
Usage: mailx -eiIUdFntBNHvV~ -T FILE -u USER -h hops -r address
             -s SUBJECT -f FILE users
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the options in  `grep`  is where you are going wrong. The "l" (Small L) option is for printing filenames and not contents of file, based on grep man:

```
  -l, --files-with-matches
      Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
      file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The
      scanning will stop on the first match.
```

So if you just remove the "-l" from first command, I think it will email you content of the file which is what you need, so command like:

```
$ grep -il "invalid" File1.csv File2.csv | xargs -I'{}' uuencode {} | mailx -s"files" mymail@gmail.com
```